# Python groupby process csv

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

i have a daily file of netowrk router utilizations.  I am trying find the max of column uIN and uOUT for each unique router(QIN) and the time it occured.

I have done a lot with Pandas and 'groupby' but can't seem to get the end result i need.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
Minute  QIN uIN uOUT
2/14/2018 16:00 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router1.network.com) 0.10221 0.21195
2/14/2018 16:05 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router1.network.com) 0.089865    0.18722
2/15/2018 16:10 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router1.network.com) 0.07482 0.1705
2/16/2018 16:15 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router1.network.com) 0.09176 0.18846
2/17/2018 16:20 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router1.network.com) 0.11816 0.11785
2/14/2018 16:00 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router2.network.com) 0.08786 0.15235
2/14/2018 16:05 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router2.network.com) 0.07777 0.19253
2/15/2018 16:10 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router2.network.com) 0.07552 0.14232
2/16/2018 16:15 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router2.network.com) 0.1291  0.18758
2/17/2018 16:20 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router2.network.com) 0.13361 0.11747
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c://router_data.csv')
df['Minute'] = pd.todatetime(df['Minute'])

df.set_index('Minute').groupby('QIN')['uIN'].resample("M").max()
```

Results:

```
Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router2.network.com) 0.13361
Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router1.network.com) 0.11816
```

The results i need:

```
2/17/2018 16:20 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router2.network.com) 0.13361
2/17/2018 16:20 Bundle-Ether1 on  (Router1.network.com) 0.11816
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest merging. You can drop 'uOUT' if necessary.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\router.csv', parse_dates=['Minute'], index_col='Minute')
df1 = df.groupby('QIN')['uIN'].max().reset_index()
df1 = df1.merge(df.reset_index(), on=['QIN', 'uIN']).set_index(['Minute', 'QIN'])

Out[191]: 
                                                                uIN     uOUT
Minute              QIN                                                     
2018-02-17 16:20:00 Bundle-Ether1 on (Router1.network.com)  0.11816  0.11785
                    Bundle-Ether1 on (Router2.network.com)  0.13361  0.11747
```

Comment: yeah that would work.  hmm. i am trying to make this more complicated than it needed i guess.  thank you.